# c# database setup

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, input, installation

I am trying to get some data stored in a database that i can query at a later date to display a record. I can make the database in visual studio 2010 no problems with all the fields i need. I just can seem to get the program to access it and add any data. I also have searched for help on the internet but they all seem to not work for me they say that the cannot find the database. I currently have no code to show because i am not sure what i should be doing. Any  good websites to view could be helpful i cant find any good ones.

thanks in advance

Comment: What database are we talking about? SQL, MySQL, Oracle ...?

Comment: i was looking at sql as i can make it from within vs2010

Comment: Then check the server explorer, more info in my answer below.

Comment: Updated my answer with another tool called SQL Server Management Studio, it may as well be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a database tool called `Server Explorer` that is shipped with visual studio 2010.

To access it navigate to `View->Server Explorer` (or `Ctrl+W,L`). Then right-click on `Data Connections` and select `Add Connection` or `Create new SQL Database`depending on your needs. Once you have a connection setup you can edit tables, insert data etc from the server explorer. If you for example have a local SQL Server running its just to select your own computer as server name (should appear in the drop down list), use windows authentication as login method and choose a name for your new db.

*Side note: the server explorer works for other databases as well but may require that you install additional connectors etc.*

---

Another good tool to manage your SQL databases is the  `SQL Server Management Studio`. It needs to be installed separately, a guide to do so is available here: [Installing SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008](http://www.asql.biz/Articoli/SQLX08/Art3_1.aspx). In my opinion this interface gives you better control of your databases, tables, stored procedures etc.

Comment: i have go that setup now but i am now not sure how to put data from an input on the program into a field

Answer (score 0):

You can find basic information about database access on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw738475.aspx).